# Is it possible to set startup applications for specific desktop environments?

Tags: cinnamon, startup-applications, docky

I would like most desktop environments (abbreviation: DEs. Including GNOME, MATE, Xfce and LXDE) on my 32-bit Ubuntu 15.04 system to not have Docky as a startup application, but I would like Docky to be a startup application in the Cinnamon DE. Is there a way to do this?  Please keep in mind I am a programming noob, so please avoid using programming discourse. Just simple step-by-step instructions, will be much appreciated. Like what do I add to which file and where?